# What is the best and fastest way to make money in Runescape?

Tags: runescape

I know you can take vials and fill them to be vials of water, and add feathers to arrow shafts, but is there anything faster and more effective?

Comment: If we can get some of your skills, i can help more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm presuming you're a low level free-to-play player, as you have mentioned both low levelled methods that are mainly used in F2P. If not, then please elaborate :).

Here are some methods:

1. Cut normal logs (the current price is 405gp)
2. Mine iron. Quick and easy
3. Collecting ashes. Burn the logs yourself then pick up ashes. Willow logs are highly recommended because they are cheap. You can do this at the Fist of Guthix lobby.
4. Farm marigolds. You need level 2 farming and the seeds are cheap. It takes 17.5 minutes to grow and you get around 3,000 gp+ back.
5. Smelt bars. One of the very few methods to make money while smithing in F2P
6. Chop yew logs. They are currently 577gp each (and I'm presuming they are rising because of the Divination update)
7. Mine runite ore. Great money, but needs 85 mining.